# Find camera tilt

Tags: image-processing, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, homography

If I have a camera that captures tilted images what is the way to find the tilt of the camera? Is there a pattern that I can photograph or something similar. I want to reduce the tilt as precisely as possible.

Comment: Tilted with respect to what?  You could certainly photograph something that shows direction strongly, and use that as a reference.  I.e. you could photograph a set of vertical or horizontal stripes, and use image processing techniques to determine how they are tilted.  But if you want to know how the camera's imaging chip is tilted with respect to its mounting plate, then you'd need to insure that the physical thing you're photographing is level with respect to the camera's mounting plate when you take the picture.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well the camera gives distorted images and after some image processing I came to the point where I can obtain images that are undistorted. However, they have a slight homographic transformation. If I take the image of a black squared piece of paper on a white level wall it would look slightly unlevel, like a trapezoid or so. How can I fix these tilted images if I don't have the equipment to place the camera perfectly perpendicular to the wall?

Comment: This gets back to "tilted with respect to what?".  If you just want to rotate the image by an arbitrary amount, go ahead.  If you want to select a square and make it level with respect to the image, there's ways to do that.  I'm not sure where you're from, but in the US I can get a cheap Chinese machinist's level for about the same price as lunch in a low to mid-priced restaurant, and that -- plus patience, rocks, strings, bits of paper and other found objects -- are all I'd need to level up a camera.

Comment: Like a sensor tilt.